# ¿Cómo utilizar automapper en un método asíncrono?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, automapper

Tengo un método de un controlador que devuelve objetos después de mapearlos con Automapper.
Necesito que me lo haga de forma asíncrona.
El método es este:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomerOrderDTO>> GetCustomerOrder()
  {
     return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CustomerOrderDTO>>(_context.CustomerOrder.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)).ToList();
  }
```

Y lo que quiero conseguir sería algo así, pero mapeado hacia el DTO:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomerOrder>>> GetCustomerOrder()
  {
     return await _context.CustomerOrder.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToListAsync();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas conseguir una conversion asincrona de una entidad de `entity framework` podrias evaluar las libreris

[AutoMapper.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.EF6/)

[AutoMapper.EFCore](https://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper.EFCore)

No se cual version de `EF` estas utilizando, pero veras que en los ejemplos utiliza

```
 var employees = await db.Employees.ProjectToListAsync();
```

o

```
 var employees = await db.Employees.ProjectTo().ToListAsync();
```

creo que se adecua a lo que mencionas

Comment: porque negativo? si entiendo es lo que esta buscando, las extensiones de EF para poder mapear las entidades de forma async. Si votan negativo expliquen con un comentario que me falto aclarar para que no sea considerado algo que aporte

Comment: Disculpa Leandro, ese click ha sido involuntario. Además ayer no estuve en la oficina, así que todavía no he podido mirar lo que me comentas en tu respuesta. A ver si puedo hoy. Gracias. Por cierto, estoy usando EFCore.